# Binary predicting time series

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, binary-data

I have a time series dataset as follows (just 1 part out of 1000 obs). The data includes only the time and the outcome (1 - success, 0 - failure). Time here is not the amount of time but the date (For example, test 1 is performed at 15:18:56 on 10/9/2012, not that it took 15 hours to complete).

Tests are independent but it is assumed that lessons learned after a failure

[image]

Questions:
(1) Do you know any package in R/ Python that could help predicting this data?
(2) How the assumption of lesson learned impact the prediction model?

Comment: It would help to have some more context here.  What are the tests?  What determines the times?  What does "it is assumed that lessons learned after a failure" mean?  What is to be predicted (success or failure given the time? time of success?)

Comment: "Lessons learned after a failure" for example the result of test 2 is fail, testers would learn failure lesson from test 2 in order to perform test 3 better

Comment: Need to predict: success or failure given the time.

Comment: It is the test of aviation. The time here is not the amount of time but the date. For example, at 15:18:56, test 1 is performed (it is not that test 1 took 15 hours to succeed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to predict the outcome based on time, where outcome is your response try using survival analysis. Your data looks like a good candidate for this analysis.

Survival regression model and Kaplan-maier estimate (probability function) are available in R. The pakage is survival. Here is a link to a good tutorial.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/survival-analysis-with-r/amp/

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the model 
\begin{align*}
y_t \mid x_t &\sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(p = \frac{e^{x_t}}{1+e^{x_t}}\right) \\
x_t - \mu  &= \phi( x_{t-1} - \mu) + w_t
\end{align*}
where $y_t$ is your $0,1$ observation and $x_t$ is some hidden state. I think the [`KFAS`](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.01907.pdf) package can handle this, but I've never used it. That vignette also mentions other software that you can use for this model.

It's  kind of a fancy model, but if you can figure it out, you'll be able to see how the probability of a $1$ changes over time in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a multi-order markov transition table with reasonable success in the past.  This should capture the possible learning after a failure to some extent.  It should be pretty easy to port this Matlab code to R or Python.

[Multi-Order Markov Transition Table](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37322-multi-order-state-transition-matrix)

Perhaps this R package does a good job of fitting high order transition tables:

[MarkovChain package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/markovchain.pdf)